# File is not created/opened when using with open

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask and testing some code in Python. I am trying to store in a log file a Flask request and a string every time a post is done.

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

from vsearch import search4letters

app = Flask(__name__)


def log_request(request, results: str) -> None:
    print(request)
    with open('vsearch.log', 'a') as log:
        print(request, results, file=log)


@app.route('/search4', methods=['POST'])
def do_search() -> 'html':
    phrase = request.form['phrase']
    letters = request.form['letters']
    title = 'Here are your results:'
    results = str(search4letters(phrase, letters))
    log_request(request, results)
    return render_template('results.html',
                           the_phrase=phrase,
                           the_letters=letters,
                           the_title=title,
                           the_results=results,
        )

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/entry')
def entry_page() -> 'html':
    return render_template('entry.html',
                           the_title='Welcome to search4letters on the web!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my HTML view:
[image]

After pressing **Do it!**, 'vsearch.log' should contained what I have printed to it, but it does not. In addition, when the file does not exists, it does not get created.

I have tried changing the mode of open to `'a+'`, but I get the same results. I have also made a debug, and these lines are just executed with no errors raised.

Could somebody explain me what is going on, and how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: It's probably being created in the wrong place. Use a full absolute path to the file.

Comment: `print(request, results, file=log)` isn't how one normally writes to file. Use `log.write` instead.

Comment: @ForceBru, I have used `log.write', and I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @AlexHall, is there any way to know where this file is being stored by default?

Comment: I'm not sure but try `import os; os.getcwd()`.

Comment: @AlexHall, you were right, using the absolute path works.

Comment: @AlexHall, how can I know where the file was created previously. I mean before providing the absolute path. I thought it was going to be created in the same directory as the file that contains my code, so why this is not happening. If you can provide an answer I will be pleased to validate it.

Comment: I really don't know why it's not being created somewhere you can see. How are you running your code? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AlexHall, I have provided an answer based on what you have suggested. I am running my project from PyCharm. Do you think that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexHall, I have been able to solve this problem. The solution is to specify the full absolute path to the file.

```
def log_request(request, results: str) -> None:
    with open('/absolute/path/to/the/file/vsearch.log', 'a') as log:
        print(request, results, file=log)
```

In addition, following @AlexHall suggestion to know the current working directory. I have seen that this is:

`/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/bin`

so when not specifying the full absolute path the file 'vsearch.log' was created here.

**EDIT:**

So, it seems that the problem was I was running my code from PyCharm. However, when I use the terminal and I just run:

```
$ python webapp.py
```

I do not need to specify the full absolute path.

**EDIT:**

I was able to solve this issue, and I probably screwed up the settings at some point, but after deleting all the run configurations in PyCharm, and running the program from `webapp.py` everything has been solved.

I really want to thank @AlexHall since he gave me all tips to solve this problem.

Comment: I use PyCharm all the time and I've never seen anything like this. How are you running the script? Where is it located?

Comment: @AlexHall, well I am just hitting the play button, and as I have explained in my answer. When running the code from the terminal it works without specifying the absolute path, and in this case the current working directory is where my file is.

Comment: What does your run configuration look like? What does it say at the beginning in the console/log when you run? Is this a plain python project?

Comment: @AlexHall, I have deleted my configurations, and from the code I have run `⌃⇧R`, and now everything is working. I probably screwed up something at some point, when I was debugging or running another file called main.py in the same directory, but thank you so much for all your help. I was able to figure it out thanks to you.

Comment: @AlexHall, answering your question of what it says at the beginning in the console:
`/path/to/python/venv/bin/python /path/to/webapp/webapp.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 958-841-160`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Flask it's much better to use the built in logging functionality. See: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/errorhandling/#logging-to-a-file

So, for example, on app startup you'd have:

```
import logging
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('/path/to/your/flask.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Then wherever you want to log something in your application you'd log to warning or above, or whatever you set the file handler log level to:

```
@app.route('/whatever')
def whatever():
    app.logger.warning('Whatever!')
    return render_template('whatever.html')
```

Comment: your answer is a good practice I should follow, and this definitely creates the file, but the output gets printed on the console, but not in the file.